# Height of a Square Pyramid Bisect Diagonal of Base?

Tags: geometry

Does the height of a square-based pyramid bisect the diagonal of the base? If so, can you show me a basic proof?

Comment: Since the height is either a line segment perpendicular to the base, or else the length of such a segment, it's not clear what it would mean for it to "bisect" the diagonal of the base. Do you mean to ask if the point where the altitude meets the base cuts the square's diagonal into two equal length parts?

Comment: There are square-based pyramids whose vertex is not over the center of the square, i.e. they are "tilted" in a sense. If this is allowed the base of a perpendicular from the vertex of the pyramid will not cut a diagonal of the square equally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble putting something in the comments section.

If this is so, namely that some altitudes drawn from the vertex of the square-based pyramid do not cut the base's diagonal into two equal parts, is it possible that sometimes it does occur? And how can one prove when or when not?